# Field bookRepo in com.restapi.test.services.BookService required a bean of type 'com.restapi.test.respository.BookRepo' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

```
    [enter image description here][1]
    
    
      [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0R4HR.png
    
    BookService Code 
    package com.restapi.test.services;
    
    import java.util.List;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
    import com.restapi.test.entity.Book;
    import com.restapi.test.respository.BookRepo;
    @Component
    
    public class BookService {
        
        
        
        
        /*
         * // Now we have implemented our database so directly we store in database and
         * fetch details // thats why list is commented out private static List<Book>
         * list = new ArrayList<>(); static { list.add(new
         * Book(12,"Complete Java Reference","XYZ")); list.add(new
         * Book(23,"Python Programmer","ABC")); list.add(new
         * Book(54,"Javascript for begginers ","JKL"));
         * 
         * }
         */
        
        // here we will take a object of repository class (in this case BookRepo)
        @Autowired
        private BookRepo bookRepo;
        
        /*
         * // Get all books
         * 
         * public List<Book> getAllBooks(){ return list;
         * 
         * }
         */
        
        public List<Book> getAllBooks(){
            List<Book> list = (List<Book>)this.bookRepo.findAll();   // Because Iterable is parent class we can Type cast 
            return list;
        }
        
        
        
        
        
        
        /*
         * // get one book // this is commented out because now we use database
         * 
         * public Book getBookById(int id) { Book book= null; try { book=
         * list.stream().filter(e->e.getId()==id).findFirst().get(); } catch(Exception
         * e){ e.printStackTrace();
         * 
         * }
         * 
         * return book; }
         */
        
        public Book getBookById(int id) {
            Book book= null;
            try {
                book = this.bookRepo.findById(id);
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                
            }
        
        return book;
        }
        
        
        
        
        
        
        /*
         * //method for adding the book // now we remove static list and use database
         * 
         * public Book addBook(Book b) { list.add(b); return b; }
         */
        
        
        // using Database 
        public Book addBook(Book b) {
           Book result =bookRepo.save(b);
           return result;
            
        }
        
        
        
        
        /*
         * //delete one book
         *  public void deleteBookbyId(int id) {
         * 
         * list = list.stream().filter(book -> { if(book.getId()!=id) { return true;
         * 
         * } else { return false; } }).collect(Collectors.toList());
         * 
         * }
         */   // same code can be reduced into these lines 
        
        //delete one book   because now we use Database so static fake service list is not used that why commented out
        /*
         * public void deleteBookById(int id) { try { list = list.stream().filter(book
         * ->book.getId()!=id).collect(Collectors.toList()); } catch(Exception e) {
         * System.out.println(e); } // }
         */
        
        public void deleteBookById(int id) {
            try {
                this.bookRepo.deleteById(id);
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
    //      
        }
        
        
        
        
        // now we use database we are not using fake service class that is why commented out
    
        /*
         * public void updateBook(Book book, int bookId) { try { list
         * =list.stream().map(b->{ if(b.getId()==bookId) {
         * b.setAuthor(book.getAuthor()); b.setTitle(book.getTitle( )); } return b;
         * }).collect(Collectors.toList()); // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         * }catch(Exception e) { System.out.println(e);
         * 
         * 
         * }
         */
            
            
            
            public void updateBook(Book book, int bookId) {
                try {
                    book.setId(bookId);
                    bookRepo.save(book);
                }catch(Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                 }
            
            
            
        } 
    }
    
    Book Enity Code 
    package com.restapi.test.entity;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.Table;
    
    @Entity 
    @Table(name="books")
    public class Book {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String title;
    private String Author;
    public Book(int id, String title, String author) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        Author = author;
    }
    public Book() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getAuthor() {
        return Author;
    }
    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        Author = author;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Book [id=" + id + ", title=" + title + ", Author=" + Author + "]";
    }
    
    }
    
    Book Repository Code 
    package com.restapi.test.respository;
    
    import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
    
    import com.restapi.test.entity.Book;
    
    public interface BookRepo extends CrudRepository<Book , Integer>{
        public Book findById(int id);
        public Book deleteById(int id);
        
    
    }
```

Explaination
I am getting this error saying everything looks fine to me
Everything looks fine but why this error , can anybody explain?

Description:

Field bookRepo in com.restapi.test.services.BookService required a bean of type 'com.restapi.test.respository.BookRepo' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
- @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.restapi.test.respository.BookRepo' in your configuration.

Comment: Can Anyone explain me why this error am getting ?

Comment: Your `BookRepo` is not being picked up. You don't need the `@Repository` annotation on JpaRepositories but you need it on CrudRepositories. Either make your repository extend JpaRepository or add the `@Repository` annotation.